# LINQ - Refactor .Contains comparison on IEnumerable<string> to be case sensitive

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, contains

I have what seems like it should be a fairly simple linq issue. I'm doing a string comparison using `Contains` that is behaving case sensitively and I need it to be case insensitive. I understand that the proper way to do this is by using the `IndexOf` method overload that  takes a `StringComparison.OrdinalIgnoreCase` argument.

The problem is that the object I'm hanging the `IndexOf` off of (emailAddresses) is an enumeration of strings so there is no `IndexOf` available. I also tried `emailAddresses.Contains(x.Email, StringComparer.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase` but it throws this error:

> LINQ to Entities does not recognize the method 'Boolean Contains[String](System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable 1[System.String], System.String, System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer 1[System.String])' method

How do I refactor this so that the `.Where(x => emailAddresses.Contains(x.Email)` portion is case insensitive?

```
public IList<string> FindInvalidEmails(UserContext userContext, IEnumerable<string> emailAddresses)
{
    var validEmails = new List<string>();

    emailAddresses.ForEachChunk(100, emailAddressesChunk =>
        validEmails.AddRange(_enterpriseRepositoryFactory.GetMemberRepository(userContext.EnterpriseId).FindAll()
                                    .Where(x => emailAddresses.Contains(x.Email) && !x.IsDeleted)
                                    .Select(x => x.Email)
                                    .ToList())
    );

    return emailAddresses.Except(validEmails).ToList();
}
```

Comment: You should make clearer that your `IEnumerable<string>` comes from Entity Framework, otherwise you will get lots of answers that actually do not work.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

How about:

```
.Where(x => emailAddresses.Select(y => y.ToLower()).Contains(x.Email.ToLower())
```

It will change all your collection elements into lowercase versions and try to find lowercased version of user email within that collection.

You could pick `ToUpper` instead, it should make no difference.

If it was a LINQ to object query, you'd probably should use `ToLowerInvariant`, but because it's not supported by LINQ to Entities, you have to use `ToLower` here`

Comment: I don't know why the comment was removed, but you're correct: `emailAddresses` is a list by itself so it has to be iterated as well rather than calling `ToLower()` on it.

Comment: @JeroenVannevel You're right! I missed that. Updated my answer.

Comment: You actually better off using `ToUpperInvariant` per [Best Practices for Using Strings in the .NET Framework](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd465121.aspx) - "Use the String.ToUpperInvariant method instead of the String.ToLowerInvariant method when you normalize strings for comparison."

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov `ToUpperInvariant` is not supported by LINQ to Entities and cannot be translated into proper SQL statement.

Comment: +1. Good point - I always fail to read every single character in posts... You probably should add at least half a sentence to explain why this code is the way it is than...

Answer (score 2):

If emailAddresses is `IEnumerable` you could do....

```
.Where(x => emailAddresses.Any(em => em.ToLower() == x.Email.ToLower())
```

or

```
//Build a list of lower emails in memory
var lowerEmails = emailAddress.Select(em => em.ToLower()).ToList();
...
.Where(x => lowerEmails.Contains(x.Email.ToLower())
```

Comment: I thought of that but won't this fail if in certain languages? I have to support Chinese, Russian, Dutch etc...

Comment: I'm not sure the `Any` version would work. There might be a problem in translating that into SQL query.